# Dynamic links is not connected properly : Path prefix is not configured

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links

I keep getting the following message in Firebase dynamic links so can someone help me?
https://deep.example_url.com is not connected properly
Your Dynamic Links path prefix is not configured in firebase.json. Check your firebase.json configuration and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the Dynamic link rewrite rule comes before the existing rule as rewrites are processed in the order they are listed. See this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/custom-domains) for additional details.

Here is an example of a fixed firebase.json:

```
{

  "hosting": {

    "public": "public",

    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],

    "appAssociation": "AUTO",

    "rewrites": [

      { "source": "/urlPrefix/**", "dynamicLinks": true},

      { "source": "/**", "destination": "index.html" }

    ]

  }

}
```